# Rails query through 2 different associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having a little trouble trying to get a query to work the way I want it, I'm not getting all the results I'm hoping for.

I have 3 models `Post`, `Comment` and `Tag`. Both the posts and the comments can contain tags, and both have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with tags. I want to be able to get all the posts that either have a specified tag or have comments with that tag, I've been doing it in the following scope on posts like so:

```
scope :tag, -> (tag_id) { joins(:tags, :comment_tags).where("tags_posts.tag_id = :tag_id OR comments_tags.tag_id = :tag_id", tag_id: tag_id) }
```

But that doesn't return all the posts, just a subset of them, seems like its only the ones regarding the comments, this is the query it generates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "tags_posts" ON "tags_posts"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tags_posts"."tag_id" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
INNER JOIN "comments_tags" ON "comments_tags"."comment_id" = "comments"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" "comment_tags_posts" ON "comment_tags_posts"."id" = "comments_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE (tags_posts.tag_id = 1 OR comments_tags.tag_id = 1)
```

These are the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comment_tags, through: :comments, source: :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain whether you've already figured this out, but in case you haven't, here is a possible solution:

In plain SQL, mainly for illustration purposes:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT posts.*
FROM
    posts
        INNER JOIN
    tags_posts ON tags_posts.post_id = posts.id
        LEFT JOIN
    comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id
        LEFT JOIN
    comments_tags ON comments_tags.comment_id = comments.id
        INNER JOIN
    tags ON (tags.id = tags_posts.tag_id OR tags.id = comments_tags.tag_id)
WHERE tags.id = 1
```

The primary issue in your original version was that you were making an `INNER JOIN` with `comments` and `comments_tags`. As a result you were probably cutting out every `Post` which did not have any comments. So the solution is to `LEFT JOIN` everything related to the comments. And then, because we are left joining, we can `INNER JOIN` `tags` on either the tag posts or comment posts.

Converting to Active Record is not very pretty, but necessary:

```
Post.joins("INNER JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.post_id = posts.id")
    .joins("LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id")
    .joins("LEFT JOIN comments_tags ON comments_tags.comment_id = comments.id")
    .joins("INNER JOIN tags ON (posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id OR comments_tags.tag_id = tags.id)")
    .where(tags: {id: 1})
    .uniq
```

Note the necessity of `DISTINCT` and `uniq`, as you will get duplicates because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

**Edit**

In case there's some misunderstanding of the dataset or structure, this is an example of the data I used in my test to create the above query.

**posts**

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | text                     |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Post about programming 1 |
|  2 | Post about programming 2 |
|  3 | Post about programming 3 |
|  4 | Post about cooking 1     |
|  5 | Post about cooking 2     |
+----+--------------------------+
```

**tags**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | programming |
|  2 | cooking     |
|  3 | woodworking |
+----+-------------+
```

**tags_posts**

```
+--------+---------+
| tag_id | post_id |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       1 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      2 |       4 |
|      2 |       5 |
+--------+---------+
```

**comments**

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+---------+
| id | comment_text                                 | post_id |
+----+----------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | comment - programming on programming post 1a |       1 |
|  2 | comment - programming on programming post 1b |       1 |
|  3 | comment - programming on programming post 2a |       2 |
|  4 | comment - cooking on programming post 3a     |       3 |
|  5 | comment - programming on cooking post 4a     |       4 |
|  6 | comment - cooking on cooking post 4b         |       4 |
|  7 | comment - cooking on cooking post 5a         |       5 |
+----+----------------------------------------------+---------+
```

**comments_tags**

```
+--------+------------+
| tag_id | comment_id |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          1 |
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          3 |
|      1 |          5 |
|      2 |          4 |
|      2 |          6 |
|      2 |          7 |
+--------+------------+
```

If I want to search for "programming", the above query will yield this result set:

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | text                     |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Post about programming 1 |
|  2 | Post about programming 2 |
|  4 | Post about cooking 1     |
|  3 | Post about programming 3 |
+----+--------------------------+
```

since we have 3 posts specifically tagged with "programming", and one comment tagged as "programming" on a differently tagged post.

Comment: I didn't catch that, I'll give this a try in a while. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @8vius No problem, hope it works out. Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Sorry to say this isn't working either. Not getting all the posts I should with it.

Comment: @8vius that's strange. Can you determine which posts are not being pulled up? Is there anything different about them that may account for this?

Comment: They're both tagged by comments, one just has the comment with the tag and the other has several comments. That's the only difference I'm seeing.

Comment: @8vius Hmm, very odd. I've gone through it again and made some more entries in my sample database, and its still coming up as (I think) it should. I realize its a crap ton of information but check out the edit, and see whether I represented your structure correctly. Let me know whether you see anything amiss.

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back to you so late, holidays and all that. I have no idea what could be wrong, the query seems fine but when I run it and I only get the posts with the tag directly related to them not the comment tagged ones. I copied and pasted your query directly just had to change posts_tags for tags_posts and a typo with comment_tags where it should be comments_tags

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what's a yum, is it a post ?

From your SQL query it seems it will count only the yum that have both a specific tag AND comment with this specific tag. What you want is to count yum that have a specific tag OR comments with this specific tag.

I would do either 2 queries one to count the yum with specific tag + one to count the yum with specific commented tags and add them both to get the total or make one query with an UNION condition.

```
scope :yums_tagged, -> (tag_id) { joins(:tags).where("tags_yums.tag_id = :tag_id", tag_id: tag_id) }
scope :comments_taged, -> (tag_id) { joins(:comment_tags).where("comments_tags.tag_id = :tag_id", tag_id: tag_id) }
```

Comment: Yes, in my case yum is what I call my posts.

Comment: I don't want 2 different results from 2 queries, I want 1 query that gets both tagged by comment and tagged in content.

Comment: I changed all instances of yum for post to make it more understandable, sorry about the confusion.